# MySQL(version 5.5): Why `JOIN` is faster than `IN` clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

[Summary of the question: 2 SQL statements produce same results, but at different speeds. One statement uses `JOIN`, other uses `IN`. `JOIN` is faster than `IN`]

I tried a 2 kinds of `SELECT` statement on 2 tables, named *booking_record* and *inclusions*. The table *inclusions* has a many-to-one relation with table *booking_record*.

(Table definitions not included for simplicity.)

First statement: (using `IN` clause)

```
SELECT
  id,
  agent,
  source
FROM
  booking_record
WHERE
  id IN
  ( SELECT DISTINCT
      foreign_key_booking_record
    FROM
      inclusions
    WHERE
      foreign_key_bill IS NULL
      AND
      invoice_closure <> FALSE
  )
```

Second statement: (using `JOIN`)

```
SELECT
  id,
  agent,
  source
FROM
  booking_record
  JOIN
  ( SELECT DISTINCT
      foreign_key_booking_record
    FROM
      inclusions
    WHERE
      foreign_key_bill IS NULL
      AND
      invoice_closure <> FALSE
  ) inclusions
  ON
  id = foreign_key_booking_record
```

with 300,000+ rows in *booking_record*-table and 6,100,000+ rows in *inclusions*-table; the 2nd statement delivered 127 rows in just 0.08 seconds, but the 1st statement took nearly 21 minutes for same records.

Why `JOIN` is so much faster than `IN` clause?

Comment: I suggest you begin to explore this question by using `EXPLAIN` on both statements and looking at the results.

Comment: The second one has one more filter `id = foreign_key_booking_record`.

Comment: The most likely explanation for the difference in performance is a difference in the generated execution plans. As other answers already indicate, the output from `EXPLAIN` will show the execution plan for each query. One big performance issue for the `IN (subquery)`: it's possible that MySQL is executing that subquery for each and every row returned by the outer query.

Comment: I'm curious if you have tried to use the filter `id = foreign_key_booking_record` in the second statement as I suggested in my answer and if it caused any difference in the performance. Please let me know if you can.

Comment: @Caffé Sorry for late reply. I tried it, and it has consistently responded in 1.1 to 1.6 seconds. That is nearly 13 to 20 times of `JOIN`

Comment: @AbhishekOza Thanks for your reply. It's much less than 21 minutes :-) and has almost solved the performance problem. I keep thinking it's not the JOIN who is making the difference in this particular case. Would you kindly test it using `EXISTS` instead of IN while keeping the additional filter `id = foreign_key_booking_record`? I really would like to learn a little bit more from your issue and I promise do not importune you anymore :-)

Comment: @Caffé I tried `EXISTS` only twice. It was 1.3 and 0.9 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is well-documented.  See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html).

The short answer is that until MySQL version 5.6.6, MySQL did a poor job of optimizing these types of queries.  What would happen is that the subquery would be run each time for every row in the outer query.  Lots and lots of overhead, running the same query over and over.  You could improve this by using good indexing and removing the `distinct` from the `in` subquery.

This is one of the reasons that I prefer `exists` instead of `in`, if you care about performance.

Answer (score 1):

EXPLAIN should give you some clues ([Mysql Explain Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

I suspect that the IN version is constructing a list which is then scanned by each item (IN is generally considered a very inefficient construct, I only use it if I have a short list of items to manually enter).

The JOIN is more likely constructing a temp table for the results, making it more like normal JOINs between tables.

Answer (score 1):

You should explore this by using EXPLAIN, as said by Ollie.

But in advance, note that the second command has one more filter: `id = foreign_key_booking_record`.

Check if this has the same performance:

```
SELECT
  id,
  agent,
  source
FROM
  booking_record
WHERE
  id IN
  ( SELECT DISTINCT
      foreign_key_booking_record
    FROM
      inclusions
    WHERE
      id = foreign_key_booking_record -- new filter
      AND
      foreign_key_bill IS NULL
      AND
      invoice_closure <> FALSE
  )
```